# Serverless framework: Set environment variables from file and stack outputs

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, serverless-framework

I am writing AWS lambda using Serverless function. At some places, I've imported variables from external YAML file as below

```
functions:
    environment: ${file(properties/env-${opt:stage}.yml)}
```

At some other place, in addition to what environment variables are present in the given file, I would like to add certain variables in the serverless file. Which in turn refers to serverless outputs from the same stack. Like below

```
functions:
   ... 
   environment:
      STATE_MACHINE_ARN: ${self:resources.Outputs.my_state_machine.Value}

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    my_state_machine:
       ...
```

How do I mix both of the above, i.e get variables from files and the state machine output?

One option, I could use is `MY_SECRET: ${file(../config.${self:provider.stage}.json):CREDS}` but the problem is I've to use this for every environment variables which defeats the purpose of declaring it in other file.

What are my other options?

Comment: You could try to add the Output variables in another yml and then reference both yml files under environment as separate entries.

Normally I'd have functions, tables, iamRoles etc in separate folders so this would match that pattern.